# how do can I make the start menu stop showing on the opposite side of start button?

Tags: windows-10, desktop, start-menu

A few days ago, probably due to some unholly combination of keys, my start menu started showing on the **opposite** side of the screen as far away from the start menu button as possible. See pic related:

[image: screenshot]

The start menu button is on the **top-right** corner while the start menu is on the **bottom-left** corner. Also, as a side effect, the search/run function no longer works, so I cannot type "putty" and press enter to run that program so, *how do I revert it back to a normal behaviour and position?*

Comment: have you tried unlocking the start menu, and dragging it? Right-click on the taskbar and choose "Lock the Taskbar".

Comment: Not working. It unlocks the _task bar_ but not the start menu. It stays firmly locked to the wrong corner.

Comment: Moving the task bar to any other side, then back to the original position seemed to work. I gues it is solved now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following seems to fix it:

- Right-clicking on the taskbar
- If checked, Uncheck "Lock all taskbars"
- Drag the taskbar to any other screen side
- Open the start menu
- Drag the taskbar back to the original place
- Open the start menu and confirm it's in the right position.
- Optionally re-lock all task bars